# Adding custom data attribute to html <option> tag within a @Html.EditorFor in an MVC Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to add a custom data attribute to each option in my selectlist, which I could achieve with jQuery.data() or .attr().

However, I am setting up my selectlists with the following html helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MySelect, MVC.Shared.Views.EditorTemplates.KeyValuePairSelectList, new { SelectListOptions = Model.MySelectList})
```

Is there a way to do it in the new{} method of the EditorFor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try using any one of the two ways described below,

**1. Using custom editor template**

Suppose we want to display `MyModel` array as a dropdownlist and the properties `SomeProperty1` and `SomeProperty2` to be displayed as **data** attributes in the **<option>** element.

```
    public class MyModel
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Value { get; set; }
      public string SomeProperty1 { get; set; }
      public string SomeProperty2 { get; set; }
    }

  // CustomSelectList.cshtml (editor template)
  @model MyModel[]

  <select>
  @foreach (var i in Model)
  {
    <option name="@i.Id" data-attr-1="@i.SomeProperty1" data-attr-2="@i.SomeProperty2">@i.Value</option>
  }
  </select>
```

**2. Using [templated razor delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx)**

```
    public static class RazorExtensions
    {
      public static HelperResult List<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items,
        Func<T, HelperResult> template)
      {
        return new HelperResult(writer =>
        {
          foreach (var item in items)
          {
            template(item).WriteTo(writer);
          }
        });
      }
    }

  // Model is MyModel[]
  <select>
  @Model.List(@<option name="@item.Id" data-attr-1="@item.SomeProperty1" data-attr-2="@item.SomeProperty2">@item.Value</option>)
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to have your own editor  extension to do this.